# What happens when I run my code again in jupyter notebook? Does it reset my model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, transfer-learning

I am training a large model on my computer which takes time. I have checkpoint and earlystopping callback. Checkpoint callback saves weights only and earlystopping is set to restore_best_weights.

I set my computer to train during the night when I go to bed. When I wake up, I see the results, close Jupyter Notebook because I have to write my thesis, and then I open Jupyter again before I go to bed to have it train again after I changed some things.

My question is, if I open the notebook again after I trained the model, I still have to execute all the cells to resume working. If I execute all the cells, like this one:

```
# Define ResNet50 base model with weights from imagenet. Do NOT include top classification layers.
base_model = tf.keras.applications.resnet_v2.ResNet50V2(input_shape=input_shape, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

# Freeze base model
base_model.trainable = False

# Define input layer
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

# Apply Data Augmentation
x = data_augmentation(inputs)

# Preproccess input using the same weights base model was trained on
x = tf.keras.applications.resnet_v2.preprocess_input(x)

# Set training = False to disable Batch Norm layers from updating
x = base_model(x, training = False)
    
# Add avaragePooling
x = tfl.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

# Add dropout layer for regularization
x = tfl.Dropout(0.2)(x)

# Add prediction/output layer with 3 neurons (Class Number = 3)
outputs = tfl.Dense(3, kernel_initializer = HeNormal())(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

base_lr = 0.004
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = base_lr), loss=CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True), metrics=["accuracy"])
```

My model will get replaced, therefore the weights that it learnt will be initialized again? Even if Early Stopping restores the best weights, those will be overwritten, right?

My workflow is:

1. Define dataset
2. Define model with data augmentation and base_model.trainable = false
3. Compile model
4. Define callbacks such as EarlyStopping, Checkpoints, ReduceLR and tensorboard
5. model.fit

Now I want to apply fine-tuning but I think when I run my code again the model's state is gone. What I thought to do is after the first training session, I do:

```
model.get_weights() # So I can see what the weights are when I first train the model
```

And then when i restart my notebook I do model.get_weights() again to see if they are the same, if they are not, I check my checkpoint_dir and see which checkpoint has the lowest val_loss and do:

```
# Load weights from the checkpoint with the lowest val_loss if model.get_weights() returns different weights
model.load_weights(r'.\checkpoints\ResNet50\run_23_07_2022-13_18_57\ckp_24-0.4337')
```

Basically, I am restoring the best weights manually.

Then continue with base_model.trainable = True, and carry on with compiling the model again and running model.fit to fine-tune it.

As you can tell, I am a bit confused on how Jupyter Notebook works and how to resume training my model after each session. Is my workflow correct, with manually loading the best checkpoint?

Do I have to keep Jupyter open until I completely finish with the project, so the variables are not gone?

Comment: Yes, or save interim results and modify your code so that it will reload the interim results.

Comment: @itprorh66 You are saying yes to the part that I need to have Jupyter open until I completely finish with the project? If I do that, then manually loading weights is pointless since early stopping will handle that for me. But if I close Jupyter I need to do it load weights manually like I do now with the checkpoints?

Comment: If you don't save your data to an independent file and then reload your data you would have to keep the notebook open until done.  Jupyter notebook doesn't keep cell computations between usages.  Every time you close the notebook and reopen it, the notebook recomputes cell values..  If you save data, then you need to update your code so that if a file with saved data exists, the cells reload this data rather than recompute.